# Surrogate character( ) from ruby on rails application gets saved to oracle database in question mark format (?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Surrogate character( ) from ruby on rails application gets saved to oracle database in question mark format (?)

Ruby -2.4.1
Rails - 5.0
Oracle - 11.2

Using above configurations

firing below query

```
UPDATE table_name SET my_message = N'テストトト VP－' WHERE table_name.MERCHANT_ID = 'merchant4'
```

While updating above record it gets saved to db as 'テストトト VP－？？'

Please suggest.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May be it’s not supported https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.5-en/charset-charsets.html

Comment: @bestinamir This is Oracle DB, not MySQL.

Comment: Try with some random emoji. This tests that >3 byte characters work.  is a 4-byte character. If you're having trouble with those characters, check that your column type supports 4-byte UTF-8.

Comment: yes, column type supports 4-byte UTF-8